# Using "If" statement to change a list values

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have a question that would be pretty trivial in almost any other language but is giving me a massive headache in *Mathematica*.

I am trying to construct an If statement check on one variable that I want to use to modify another variable. The problem is that while it works perfectly well if I ask it to test a single element of a list for the condition it works fine:

```
Sample = {1, 65, -40, 120};               
Sample2 = {5, 10, 15, 20};

If[Sample[[1]] < 60, Sample2[[1]] + 20, Sample2[[1]]]
```

> 25

But for the life of me I cannot figure out the proper syntax to ask it to iterate through the entire list to check each element of the list `Sample` being used in the `If` statement and then update the corresponding `Sample2` list element.

```
If[Sample < 60, Sample2 + 20, Sample2]
```

> If[{1, 65, -40, 120} < 60, Sample2 + 20, Sample2]

```
If[Sample[[All]] < 60, Sample2[[All]] + 20, Sample2[[All]]]
```

> If[{1, 65, -40, 120} < 60, Sample2[[All]] + 20, Sample2[[All]]]

Etc, etc...

I feel like there must be a very simple and streamlined solution to this simple problem that I am just overlooking, but I have been up and down the documentation as well as other stackexchange pages and nothing is jumping out at me. I've spent way too much time on this as is...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `MapThread`

```
MapThread[If[# < 60, #2 + 20, #2] &, {Sample, Sample2}]
```

or alternatively

```
Sample2 + 20 Boole[Thread[Sample < 60]]
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an elegant solution! Thank you so much. Another tool to add to my Mathematica toolbox!

Answer (score 6):

Either

```
Sample = {1, 65, -40, 120};
Sample2 = {5, 10, 15, 20};

Do[If[Sample[[i]] < 60, Sample2[[i]] = Sample2[[i]] + 20, Sample2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[Sample]}]

Sample2
```

> {25, 10, 35, 20}

or

```
Sample = {1, 65, -40, 120};
Sample2 = {5, 10, 15, 20};

Sample2 = 
 Table[If[Sample[[i]] < 60, Sample2[[i]] + 20, Sample2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[Sample]}]
```

also gives

> {25, 10, 35, 20}

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling there was a way to do it with "Do" as well but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
With[{p = UnitStep[60 - Sample]},  Sample2 + p 20]
```

> {25, 10, 35, 20}

```
Inner[If[# < 60, #2 + 20, #2] &, Sample, Sample2, List]
```

> {25, 10, 35, 20}

Answer (score 4):

```
fun[a_, b_] := If[a < b, b + 20, b]
SetAttributes[fun, Listable]
fun[sample, sample2]
```

> {25, 10, 35, 20}

give to the function the attribute Listable

another option :

```
test = Transpose[{sample, sample2}]
If[# === Sort[#], #[[2]] + 20, #[[2]]] & /@ test
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Function[{x,y},If[x<60,y+20,y],Listable][Sample,Sample2]

(* {25,10,35,20} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sample1 = {1, 65, -40, 120};
sample2 = {5, 10, 15, 20};

KeyValueMap[If[#1 < 60, #2 + 20, #2] &] @ AssociationThread[sample1 -> sample2]
```

{25, 10, 35, 20}

Tested with 10^6 elements (0.042 sec) this is 10 times faster than the similar looking `MapThread` (0.443 sec) and beaten only by `Table` (0.027 sec) and supersonic `UnitStep` (0.0012 sec)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Reap`/`Sow`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
sample1 = {1, 65, -40, 120};
sample2 = {5, 10, 15, 20};
First@Last@
  Reap@Scan[ If[First@# < 60, Sow[Last@# + 20], Sow[Last@#]] &, 
    Transpose@{sample1, sample2}]
```

{25, 10, 35, 20}